# Trying to hide/show/toggle with click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to minimize as much code as possible and not sure how to go about doing so.  The code I currently have works but it's taking up a lot of space and I know this can be a lot smaller than what I currently have.  If you can help point me in the right direction that would be great.

HTML (updated)

```
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q1</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A1</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q2</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A2</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q3</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A3</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q4</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A4</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q5</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A5</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q6</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A6</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q7</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A7</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q8</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A8</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q9</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ANS">A9</p>
    <p id="FAQ"><strong>Q10</strong>
        <p>
            <p class="ANS">A10</p>
```

CODE (updated)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  $("[class*='ANS']").hide();
  $('[id*="FAQ"]').on('click', function() {
    $("[class*='ANS']").not($(this).next('p')).hide();
    $(this).next('p').toggle();
  });
 });
```

This is a click function to hide/show/toggle based on what's clicked.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit notes:  Thank you all.  I read all of your comments and fixed the code.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a quick fix for this. If you want this to be done properly, use same class name for the main `<p>` and content `<p>`.

To fix this the proper way see this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/4pg4rLk9/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[class*='ANS']").hide();
  $('[id*="FAQ"]').on('click', function() {
    $("[class*='ANS']").not($(this).next('p')).hide();
    $(this).next('p').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="FAQ1"><strong>Q1</strong></p>
<p class="ANS1">A1</p>
<p id="FAQ2"><strong>Q2</strong></p>
<p class="ANS2">A2</p>
<p id="FAQ3"><strong>Q3</strong></p>
<p class="ANS3">A3</p>
<p id="FAQ4"><strong>Q4</strong></p>
<p class="ANS4">A4</p>
<p id="FAQ5"><strong>Q5</strong></p>
<p class="ANS5">A5</p>
<p id="FAQ6"><strong>Q6</strong></p>
<p class="ANS6">A6</p>
<p id="FAQ7"><strong>Q7</strong></p>
<p class="ANS7">A7</p>
<p id="FAQ8"><strong>Q8</strong></p>
<p class="ANS8">A8</p>
<p id="FAQ9"><strong>Q9</strong></p>
<p class="ANS9">A9</p>
<p id="FAQ_10"><strong>Q10</strong><p>
<p class="ANS_10">A10</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  This is what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @user4739731 eventhough this works, I would like to say that this is not the proper way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much better code:

```js
$('.faq').click(function(){
  $('.ans').hide();
  $(this).next().show();
});
```

```css
.ans {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="faq" id="FAQ1"><strong>Q1</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS1">A1</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ2"><strong>Q2</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS2">A2</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ3"><strong>Q3</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS3">A3</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ4"><strong>Q4</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS4">A4</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ5"><strong>Q5</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS5">A5</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ6"><strong>Q6</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS6">A6</p>
    <p id="FAQ7"><strong>Q7</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS7">A7</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ8"><strong>Q8</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS8">A8</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ9"><strong>Q9</strong>
    </p>
    <p class="ans ANS9">A9</p>
    <p class="faq" id="FAQ_10"><strong>Q10</strong>
        <p>
            <p class="ans ANS_10">A10</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use common class to achieve the result and use various DOM traversal method to toggle the answer.

Here in the example I have wrapped the Q & A in container div.

```
<div>
  <p class="FAQ"><strong>Q1</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="ANS">A1</p>
</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".FAQ").on('click', function() {
    $('.ANS').hide();
    $(this).closest('div').find('.ANS').toggle();
    ////You can also use .next()
    //$(this).next('.ANS').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.ANS {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p class="FAQ"><strong>Q1</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="ANS">A1</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p class="FAQ"><strong>Q2</strong>
  </p>
  <p class="ANS">A3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify a little your html, adding the "name" property, to make a general search for all items that have that property.

Then you would perform a dynamic validation of the elements:

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {

     /*hide all answers*/
     $("p[class*='ANS']").hide();
  
     /*to show a answer*/
     $("p[name*='FAQ']").click(function(e){
         
         var name = $(this).attr("name");
         
         var index = name.indexOf("FAQ") + 3;
         var number = name.substring(index , name.length);
         var selector = ".ANS"+number;
         var element = $(selector);
         var status = element.is(":visible");
         
         if(status){
          element.hide();    
         }else{ 
          element.toggle();
         }
         
     });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="FAQ1" name="FAQ1"><strong>Q1</strong></p>
<p class="ANS1">A1</p>
<p id="FAQ2" name="FAQ2"><strong>Q2</strong></p>
<p class="ANS2">A2</p>
<p id="FAQ3" name="FAQ3"><strong>Q3</strong></p>
<p class="ANS3">A3</p>
<p id="FAQ4" name="FAQ4"><strong>Q4</strong></p>
<p class="ANS4">A4</p>
<p id="FAQ5" name="FAQ5"><strong>Q5</strong></p>
<p class="ANS5">A5</p>
<p id="FAQ6" name="FAQ6"><strong>Q6</strong></p>
<p class="ANS6">A6</p>
<p id="FAQ7" name="FAQ7"><strong>Q7</strong></p>
<p class="ANS7">A7</p>
<p id="FAQ8" name="FAQ8"><strong>Q8</strong></p>
<p class="ANS8">A8</p>
<p id="FAQ9" name="FAQ9"><strong>Q9</strong></p>
<p class="ANS9">A9</p>
<p id="FAQ_10" name="FAQ10"><strong>Q10</strong><p>
<p class="ANS_10">A10</p>
```